# reading xml data using python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

i have some data in xml like:

```
<test a=10 b=20>Hello</test>
<test a=30 b=40>Hi</test>
```

how do i read value of a, b as well as Hello, and Hi.
I have done some thing like:

```
tt = xml.findall('test')
no  = len(tt)
for i in range (0, no):
    print tt[i].get(a)
    print tt[i].get(b)
    print xml.findtext('test')
```

this code outputs

```
10 20 Hello
30 40 Hello
```

which is wrong for second iteration it should print "Hi" in stead of "Hello".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply iterate over the return list of `xml.findall()` rather than using indexes. Something like -

```
tt = xml.findall('test')
no  = len(tt)
for t in tt:
    print t.get('a')
    print t.get('b')
    print t.text
```

When you do - `xml.findtext()` runs the xpath on the complete xml again and gets the text for the first element it finds, that is why you are getting the issue. Just get the `.text` attribute from the xml element returned by `xml.findall()` as done above.

Answer (score 0):

Here `Python Doc` says about `findtext`

> **findtext(match, default=None)** 
> Finds text for the first subelement matching match.  match may be a tag name or path.  Returns the text
>   content of the first matching element, or default if no element was
>   found.  Note that if the matching element has no text content an empty
>   string is returned.

It always find the `first` `subelement` matching `match` hence always `Hello`.